# MongoDB - Permission denied for socket: 127.0.0.1:27025

Tags: linux, mongodb, sockets, redhat, systemd

I am getting an erro log after the reboot of Redhat 7

```
listen(): bind() failed errno:13 Permission denied for socket: 127.0.0.1:27025
systemd[1]: mongod.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
```

***mongod.service***

```
[Unit]
  Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
  After=network.target

 [Service]
   User=mongod
   Group=mongod
   Environment="OPTIONS=--quiet -f /etc/mongod1.conf"
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS run
   ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
   ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown root:root /var/run/mongodb
   ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
   PermissionsStartOnly=true
   PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod1.pid


 [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

***mongod1.conf***

```
#systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /home/telenstanley/mongod1.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo/db1
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
  mmapv1:
    smallFiles: true
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: false  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod1.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27025
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


#security:
 # authorization: enabled
#operationProfiling:

replication:
  oplogSizeMB: 1024
  replSetName: testrep
#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options
```

I am not able to find any useful answer for my problem yet.but the mongod starts successfully by running as root user from cmd

> sudo mongod -f mongod1.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found the answer after a couple of time..

> You must configure SELinux to allow MongoDB to start on Red Hat Linux-based systems (Red Hat Enterprise Linux or CentOS Linux).

The permission issue is solved by making access to the relevant ports (e.g. 27017) for SELinux if in enforcing mode. See Default MongoDB Port for more information on MongoDB’s default ports. For default settings, this can be accomplished by running

```
semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27025
```

Comment: this save me after days to days debuging

Answer (score 1):

My mongod.service has

```
  ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
```

instead of

```
  ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown root:root /var/run/mongodb
```

The owner is mongod instead of root.

Comment: Did you check all mongo folders owner?